# Submit goes to 404

Tags: 404

I have an inconsistent problem with an installation that serves the 404 page *sometimes* after the submit button is pressed. This happens on anything including entries to administrative actions. Does anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: Could you expand? What is the URL you land on when submitting an entry form when it's ok, versus when it 404s? Is this front end as well? Have you upgraded anything recently? How long has it been occurring?

Comment: When the submit button works (and this seems to be on all sorts of functions, not just channel entries) the return URL is the control panel - as you would expect. When it doesn't work the front end website 404 page is displayed.

Comment: I've seen this happen where your servers mod_security rules are very strict. Might be worth creating the error and noting the time, then talk to your web host to see if it's one of the rules that's tripping things up - your host can disable any offending rules for you.

Comment: This problem *magically* disappeared. So hosting probably the reason.